# Thorpe 15.4 Differential Geometry (Parameterized Surfaces)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I was going through practice problems in my textbook and I came this

[image]

And promptly managed to get stuck for a few hours.

I don't entirely understand the question. To the best of my understanding, the surface produced by a parameterized n-surface IS the image of some subset of its domain that its one to one on. Based off of that, the question seems like an oxymoron? I'm not entirely sure on how to proceed or even begin for that matter.

Thanks in advanced.

Edit: Forgot to post theorem 2

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I asked my professor. The example he gave was

$x \mapsto (x^2, x^3)$

Since the normal doesn't exist at $x = 0$